# How do I match a user with or without a country code from phone contacts to user in the database where user identity is a country code+phone number?

Tags: database, contacts

I have database with contact numbers.
In that,
Suppose User A saved my Contact number as 9876543120 (w/o country code) ,

**My App invite user with their phone number.**

User X invited me with Contact number +919876543120, then i will not get invitation. because database store my number as 9876543120.

User B saved my Contact number as 9876543120(with country code & same as database has),then i will get invitation.

User C saved my Contact number like 919876543120 (with country code but no + symbol), then i will not get invitation. because database store my number as 9876543120. and

User D saved my Contact Number like 09876543120(w/o country code but prefix with 0), then i will not get invitation. because database store my number as 9876543120.

Its ok for User B for sending invitation but not for other.

How to handle such situation. please Help me.
Thank you

Comment: Well I suppose you want to filter on the last ten chars of the input string, rather than the whole string. Having said that, user B will have a match for records of ANY country - I suppose that's OK if you're working on a local application for one country, but will fail as you try to take it global, simplye because you DIDN'T STORE the country so tel.no. 9876543210 will be selected in all countries.

Comment: i am working on global region.

Comment: Well, then I guess you should store the country code?? Cause several users can have the SAME telno 9876543210 if they're in different countries.

Comment: i think its not a good idea. it will increase the database size and fetching data from the data will be tedious job.